# About a Sylow subgroup of a product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ and $K$ subgroups of $G$ such that $G=HK$. Show that there exists a $p$-Sylow subgroup $P$ of G such that $P=(P\cap H)(P\cap K)$.

I looked at the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42495/sylow-subgroups), but I can't understand step "(3)  It is clear in this situation that $P=(P\cap H)(P\cap K)$." Help.

Comment: This should be a comment there, not a new question.

Comment: I tried to put it as a comment there but I don't know how?

Comment: @user28083: You don't have enough reputation yet to make a comment in someone else's question.

Comment: @user28083: The comment by Jack Schmidt suggests one way of doing it: note that $|G|=|HK|=|H||K|/|H\cap K|$, and $|(P\cap H)(P\cap K)|=|P\cap H||P\cap K|/|P\cap H\cap K|$. Show that this equals the largest power of $p$ that divides $|G|$.

Comment: |G|/ |(P∩H)(P∩K)|=(|H||K||P∩H∩K|)/(|P∩H||P∩K||H∩K|) is not divisible by p ==>|(P∩H)(P∩K)| is the largest p power that divides the order of G. Thank you very much.